# como obter o posicionamento de imagem usando draggable

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

como posso obter através de um input a escala (left e top) de posicionamento da imagem que esta sendo movimentada com o draggable.

O objetivo dessa dúvida é para que possa salvar no Banco de Dados usando PHP e Mysql, o posicionamento desejável da imagem.

Abaixo anexo parte do código usado.
Se alguém puder ajuda, ficarei muito grato.
Desde já meus agradecimentos pela a atenção dos amigos.

Código usado:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<style>
#draggable { width: auto; height: auto; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="draggable">

<img src="../../upload/portuga_logo.png" id="draggable" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="cursor: move; position: relative; left: 2px; top: 5px;" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisas de passar um objeto para esse método com a callback para correres o código que queres.

Aqui fica [um exemplo da documentação](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) do plugin:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
      start: function() {
        // correr código aqui...
      },
      drag: function() {
        // correr código aqui...
      },
      stop: function() {
        // correr código aqui...
      }
});
```

Neste exemplos tens 3 momentos diferentes que podes oscultar e correr código quando esse evento acontece.

Para saberes a posição podes usar assim dentro dessas funções:

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
var xPos = offset.left;
var yPos = offset.top;
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/2rf3mxfg/

Comment: Valeu Sergio funcionou, agora eu consigo visualizar as escalas de left e top da imagem ao move-la.
A sua dica foi de grande valia.
Mas abusando um pouco mais, tem como você me mostrar como criar um input para que eu possa pegar essas escalas e enviar para o banco de dados via form php.
Desde já meu obrigado.

Comment: @MuriloCabral precisas de `touch` também ou só `mouse`?